# cannot move individual objects in a collection

Tags: transforms

I am a beginner of Blender and stuck on moving objects, Here is my collection list
[image]
I can only move all objects within the collection whenever any objects selected, but cannot move individual objects such as donut or icing. who can help me out?

Comment: Unchecking "Proportional Editing Objects" solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the problem, but it might be locked layers... to find out, go to the top right corner of the layers menu:
[image: 1]

in the drop down menu, select this icon:
[image: 2]

and it will add the lock/unlock icon beside the layers... should be able to see if they're locked.
[image: 3]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I found it is due to "Proportional Editing Objects" checked

Comment: @banz Locking collections will not result in moving objects collectively.